# UIViewController programmatic launch/ replace

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, uiviewcontroller

I have some delegate code that I would like to replace the current view controller with another one. Both view controllers are init through Interface Builder and declared there.

How would I replace the current view, or better yet simply switch to another view controller using interfaceBuilder-initialized viewcontrollers?

What connections do I need to make in interfaceBuilding?

Thanks!

Comment: please add your code to explain what have you tried and what you want to be done?

Comment: oh hey... just did (sort of) in the answer below in the comment. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using storyboards, you may want to start with something like this :

```
UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
```

Comment: how would I push that view controller though?

Comment: UIViewController *SyncViewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SyncViewController"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:SyncViewController2 animated:YES];

Comment: Have you solved your problem ? Can you give more detail about what you want ? How your app is organized ?

Comment: i made my app the standard way, following some instructions... all of the view controllers are declared in the IB. there is a root view controller... its the tab view controller and I dont even know its name. The code that I pasted above does not work... the view controller isnt switched, and yes that method gets called. nothing happens. i assume navigationController doesnt refer to the root viewcontroller. No errors or warnings.

Comment: Do you mean you don't change viewController when you press a button of the tab bar ?

Comment: this code: UIViewController *SyncViewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SyncViewController"]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:SyncViewController2 animated:YES];    does not work at all though.

Comment: How do you want to present the new view controller ? Maybe you need a modal segue ? On your storyboard, ctrl-drag from the parent VC to the child VC and select modal. In the code, launch the segue with *[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfSegue"];*. I don't really understand what you want to do, but maybe it's something like that ?

Comment: ah thx ok. now that ive thought about it modal seems to fit the circumbstances. hwoever  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalToSync"];
 is complaining about the selector performseguewithidentifier doenst exit

Comment: Are you trying to leave the modal view ? If so, you have to do *[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];* in your modal VC

Comment: yeah I solved the question... I needed to make a UINavigationController connected to another view controller, do get the code in the answer to work. Then everything worked. thx a lot!